# How do I extract an object from an array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Data

```
$scope.people = [
  {'name':'james'},
  {'name':'ann'}
];
```

Function

```
$scope.user = $filter('filter')($scope.people, function(user){
  return user.name == 'james';
});
```

View

```
{{user | json}}
```

But, in the view (and in the console) I get an array `[]` with inside the object. I want just the object, not the array. So that I can do things like:

```
{{user.name}}
```

Comment: When you filter an array, you get an array as the result.... and a JavaScript Array is an Object, so what was the question again?

Answer (score 0):

Filter record from array in JavaScript or fetch single record of array, This feature provide javascript, you don't need any AngularJS code. Whenever you can do by only javascript, I suggest don't use angularJS filter. Create your own AngularJS filter when you want to reuse it.

You can extract object from array by below code

Data

```
$scope.people = [
  {'name':'james'},
  {'name':'ann'}
];
```

Function

```
$scope.user = function(username) {
    return $scope.people.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.name === username;
    })[0];
}
```

View

```
{{user('james') | json}}
```

`filter` is javascript prototype for array, We can filter some record by custom condition. `[0]` indicate that we just want to first record which match. we don't want array.